# django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(4)

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql

I added fields to my model but it's causing errors on migrate in production.
I looked at various proposals on fixing this but couldn't get them working. Possible I'm not implementing them well.
Would somebody be knowing the exact cause for this????
This is the error message.

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 243, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 104, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 487, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 142, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(4)
```

These are the model fields I added.

```
class Books(models.Model):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    YEAR = [(str(a), str(a)) for a in range(now.year-60, now.year+1)]
    publication_year= models.CharField('Year of publication',max_length=10000,null=True,blank=True,choices=YEAR,help_text="Optional field")
    numeric = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9]*$', 'Only  numeric characters are allowed.')
    isbn = models.CharField('ISBN', max_length=13,null=True,blank=True, help_text='13 Character ISBN number(Optional field)', validators=[numeric])
    edition = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True,blank=True,help_text="Optional field")
```

Comment: have you given max_length to the field you are trying add?

Comment: I would suggest some time spent reading [Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by deleting the most recent migration files, ran `makemigrations` and `migrate` and it worked.